# How do you find the maximum value in a column, skipping to every nth value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

Using LibreOffice's Calc program (nearly the same functionality as Microsoft Excel) I have a set of numbers in column T, which represent numbers for the week (with labels in S). Each week's worth of data is 3 rows, then a blank row separating it from the next week:

```
S |  T
=======

A | 90
B | 180
C | 250

A | 95
B | 160
C | 255

A | 100
B | 175
C | 260

A | 95
B | 185
C | 230
```

Is there a way to calculate the maximum value up until a cell, skipping to every nth row? The data in the other columns for each week and number group is based off the previous week's data in column T, but I would like to use the highest value to date.

Using the data above as an example: for weeks 1, 2, and 3, I would like the B formula to return 180, but on week 4 (where there is a higher number), 185. For the A group, week 1 would be base on 90, then 95 for week 2, 100 for week 3, but then 100 again for week 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just keep comparing the current week's value with the previous week's maximum value.

For the first week, use a formula of the pattern `=`*this week's value*

[image: First week's formula]

For every other week use a formula `=MAX(`*this week's value*`,`*last week's maximum*`)`

[image: Other weeks' formula]

Because the relative positions are the same as you go down, you can copy this formula to all the other cells. In this example, you can select one blank cell and three cells with formulas, copy, then select the next blank cell to the final cell you want to contain a formula, then paste.

Answer (score 2):

In Excel you could use an "array formula" like this to get max value for "A"

`=MAX(IF(A1:A100="A",B1:B100))`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

AS you add more data for each week the max value would update

I don't know whether this works in libreoffice......

Answer (score 0):

Do you need tto have your data organized the way you have shown?  This becomes simple (in Excel 2007) if you put all the data for each week in the same row:

[image: sample spreadsheet with weeks entered as rows]

Answer (score 0):

Excel has now added the `MAXIFS()` function which makes this much simpler. If your data starts in `S2` (which it appears to based on your formatting), you can put this formula in `U2`:

```
=IF(S2="","",MAXIFS(T$1:T2,S$1:S2,S2))
```

You can then copy / paste that down into every cell in column `U`. The fixed references (`T$1` & `S$1`) will not changed but the relative references (`T2` & `S2`) will update to the appropriate row.

How this works:

1. First, check if the label in `S` is blank. If it is, then be blank.
2. Find the max value in `T` up to the current row but only if the value in `S` matches the value in `S` for the current row. IE, get all the values at or above this row where the label is the same and then find the max of just those values.