# Determining whether each row has the highest value within the group specified in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

We want to find the row with highest priority.

We have about 30,000 rows of data in a `Table` like this:

```
Item  Group  Priority  Highest(formula wanted)
A                              TRUE
B     P           2.2          TRUE
C     P             1          FALSE
D                              TRUE
E     Q             2          FALSE
F     Q             4          TRUE
G     Q             1          FALSE
```

(Note: a priority is present if and only if there is a group. No tie exists in our data.)

The column `Highest` is `TRUE` if the row has no `Group`, or within the same group it has the highest priority. In the example above, Item `C` belongs to Group `P` but is not of the highest priority. Items `E` and `G` are of Group `Q` but don't have highest priority.

I have tried the following *array formula* (also seen [here](https://superuser.com/questions/470574/how-do-you-find-the-maximum-value-in-a-column-skipping-to-every-nth-value/470579#470579)):

`=IF([@Group]="",TRUE,MAX(([Group]=[@Group])*[Priority]))`

However, for some reason we do **not** accept array formula. Sorting is also not accepted as the original ordering is important in other calculations. Then, how can we set the formula?

Comment: The situation is like this: an add-in retrieves data from a database and automatically generate a data table in a spreadsheet. The add-in allows us to create custom columns, but once the add-in refreshes the data tables, the formula in customs column becomes non array formula. If we use array formula, we have to go to the formula, then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter every time the table refreshes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=OR([@Group]="",LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(0,1/(1+([Group]=[@Group])*[Priority])),[Priority])=[@Priority])`

On a side, I am very interested in knowing your reason for not allowing array formulas. Would you mind sharing it?

Regards

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain how the formula works?  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234 There's a general explanation here: http://excelxor.com/2015/02/22/return-entry-corresponding-to-maximum-value-based-on-conditions/